# compare object value with length of array in an object with javascript

Tags: javascript

EDIT: SOLVED See final solution below

EDIT: The value names are not the same

object 1

```
var obj1 = {
    val1a : 4,
    val2a : 3 ,
    val3a : 7
}
```

object 2 with arrays

```
var obj2 = {
    val1b : [one, two, three],
    val2b : [oneA, twoA, threeA],
    val3b : [oneB]
}
```

I am trying to do is the following

```
if(obj1.val1a  === obj2.val1b.length){
// code
}
```

but I do not want it to be so specific. Is there a way to loop over each object and return the values of obj2 that do not match obj1

SOLUTION with underScore

```
   function checkData(obj1, obj2) {

        result = []

        var keys_obj1 = Object.keys( obj1)

        var keys_obj2 = Object.keys( obj2)         

        _.each(keys_obj1, function(num, i){
            if(obj1[keys_obj1[i]].length  !== obj2[keys_obj2[i]]) {
               result.push(keys_obj1[i]);
            }
        })
        return result;

    }
```

Comment: Are the keys in each object related by name? If so how? Or do you just want to compare ordinally?

Comment: How are you structuring your data?

Comment: they are never the same ? there is any pattern? it always will be val[i]a for the first obj and val[i]b for the second obj?

Comment: no they are always different, If they were the same then the answer would be easy because you could match names

Comment: Do they always have the val[num][letter] pattern tho, or would an object have the keys `orange`, `moose`, `gopher`, for example?

Comment: @Andy yes obj2 will always have the patterns that are in the example

Comment: I rewrote the answer, check if it suits your question now

Comment: you don't need to use underScore.js, check my answer....

Comment: yes I know underscore is not needed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>The best way to do this is if both objects have the same name (for a given pair), then using [The For/In Loop](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp) iterate over one of them and return the value of both, and then compare.</strike>

Remade the fiddle using [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to make an array of keys for both objects, now it works even when the keys aren't the same (following the object index)

```js
var obj1 = {
    val1a : 4,
    val2a : 3 ,
    val3a : 7
}

var obj2 = {
    val1b : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    val2b : ['oneA', 'twoA', 'threeA'],
    val3b : ['oneB']

}

var keys_obj1 = Object.keys( obj1 )
var keys_obj2 = Object.keys( obj2 )

for (i = 0; i < keys_obj1.length; i++) {
    console.log(keys_obj1[i]+'-'+obj1[keys_obj1[i]])
    console.log(keys_obj2[i]+'-'+obj2[keys_obj2[i]].length);
    if(obj1[keys_obj1[i]]  === obj2[keys_obj2[i]].length) {
        //match
    }
}
```

console output :

```
"val1a-4"
"val1b-3"
"val2a-3"
"val2b-3"
"val3a-7"
"val3b-1"
```

Comment: Unfortunately the names are not the same ; / otherwise yes this would work

Answer (score 0):

If your model is not the definitive one, you could use an array of object like :

```
var object = [
   {table : [one, two, three], length : 3},
   {table : [one, two, three], length : 4},
... ];
```

and compare values using :

```
object[i].table.length === object[i].length
```

It's a little bit different from your model

but i hope it may helps.

Answer (score 0):

Quite long-winded, but the only way I could think to do it:

```
// for each object you are going to...
function pullData(obj) {
    var out = {};
    var token;

    // grab the keys
    var keys = Object.keys(obj).map(function (el) {

      // token is the character at the end of the key
      // the key that is returned is the key without the token
      token = el.slice(-1)
      return el.slice(0, 4);
    });

    // for each key, add it to the output object
    for (var i = 0, l = keys.length; i < l; i++) {
     out[keys[i]] = obj[keys[i] + token]
    }

    // return an object containing the data and the token
    return {data: out, token: token};
}

// take both the output from both objects being parsed
function isNotMatch(obj1, obj2) {
    var out = [];

    // loop over the first object using the now identical keys
    for (var p in obj1.data) {

        // check the values and lengths
        // if they're not the same push the key and the token as a string
        // to the output array
        if (obj1.data[p] !== obj2.data[p].length) {
          out.push(p + obj2.token);
        }
    }

    // return the array of non-matches
    return out;
}

isNotMatch(pullData(obj1), pullData(obj2));
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/andyuws/7j19ruw0/2/)

Answer (score -1):

UPDATED:
Maybe something like this. You would have to make sure the property names are the same:

```
var obj1 = {
    val1a : 4,
    val2a : 3 ,
    val3a : 7
};

var obj2 = {
    val1a : ['one', 'two', 'three'],
    val2a : ['oneA', 'twoA', 'threeA'],
    val3a : ['oneB']
};

for(var name in obj1) {
    if(obj1[name]  === obj2[name].length) {
        alert("match");
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated. I thought the `i` in `for(var i in obj1)` was an index, but it is the name of the property name.